# filling missing data with mean in pandas dataframe Error: U4 cannot be converted to a FloatingDtype

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

train1=train1.fillna('mean')

TypeError: <U4 cannot be converted to a FloatingDtype

imputed values of mean were expected

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you would show an example of what is in your train1 DataFrame. But I guess you don't have only floats in there. One solution might be to convert to float first?

`train1_imputed = float(train1).fillna('mean')`

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a function to `fillna` or a name of function. Try:

```
train1 = train1.fillna(train1.mean())
```